# Content Export in Ektron with source language as English U.S

Tags: ektron

In Ektron the default source language is English (U.S).But I need to export a content in Ektron with source language as Dutch and Target language as English U.S. I am using Ektron 8.0.

Anyone please provide me the code to export like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using

Ektron.Cms.LocalizationAPI m_objLocalizationApi = new Ektron.Cms.LocalizationAPI();

```
m_objLocalizationApi.ContentLanguage = source language;
```